# Updating table using dynamic query

Tags: sql-server

```
SET @TempTable = 'UPDATE #TempTable SET AvgVal = ' + @AvgVal + '
WHERE PropertyName =''' + @PropertyName + '''' +  ' AND CrudeName =''' +  @crudeName + ''''
```

I have an update query which is dynamic. AvgVal is float. The variable has the same datatype in the table as well. Still I get an error saying -
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
If i convert the value to varchar it works. Whats the workaround for this.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic query?

Comment: You need to explicit cast the @AvgVal to varchar...

Comment: all the parameters change dyanmically in a do while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call the "workaround" is the answer.  SQL Server uses the + operator as both addition and string concatenation.  However, because the addition operator has a slightly higher precedence than the concatenation operator, the addition operator is assumed to apply first.

See the SQL Server BOL on [Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx).  At the 3rd level of precedence, the order goes:

```
+ (Positive)
- (Negative)
+ (Add)
+ (Concatenate)
- (Subtract)
& (Bitwise AND),
^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR)
| (Bitwise OR)
```

To see how this affects queries take the following example:

```
select '1' + 2
```

The result of this query is not an error.  SQL Server interprets the + as addition.  It sees the number 2 is an integer, so it tries to convert the string '1' into an integer and is successful.  The result is the integer 3.

However, try this:

```
select '1.0' + 2
```

SQL Server again sees this as an addition, notes that 2 is an integer, and tries to convert the string '1.0' into an integer.  This conversion fails with the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '1.0' to data type int.

In your example, SQL Server detects the float @AvgVal and attempts to convert the string 'UPDATE #TempTable SET AvgVal = ' into a float.  The conversion fails spectacularly, and the error you reported occurs.

One possibility is to convert the @AvgVal into a string first:

```
SET @TempTable = 'UPDATE #TempTable
    SET AvgVal = ' + CAST(@AvgVal AS VARCHAR) + '
    WHERE PropertyName =''' + @PropertyName + '''' +  '
    AND CrudeName =''' +  @crudeName + '''
```

**Note: This query is vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!**  To avoid a SQL injection attack, always pass data to a dynamic query as parameters:

```
SET @TempTable = N'UPDATE #TempTable SET AvgVal = @AvgVal
WHERE PropertyName = @PropertyName AND CrudeName = @crudeName'
exec sp_executesql @TempTable,
    N'@AvgVal float, @PropertyName varchar(255), @crudeName varchar(255)',
    @PropertyName = @PropertyName,
    @CrudeName = @crudeName
```

This both avoids a SQL injection attack and avoids the conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

I see. Sorry, misunderstood.

Yes, because of the way SQL Server works. You are building a concatenated string. You will have to do the CAST.  Type conversions in SQL Server are a little wonky. You would think it would inherently cast to the simplest data type, varchar, but in this instance it isn't.  So you will have to do ... + CAST(@AvgVal AS VARCHAR(255)) + ...

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind some times variables like  @PropertyName  if is Nvarchar type you should do

in front of the string  N'

DECLARE  @TempTable NVARCHAR

SET @TempTable = N'UPDATE  and so on for the rest